# 'List of Algorithms' title is not all in caps

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, capitalization, algorithm2e

In my dissertation, I have added a page for list of algorithms, using `\listofalgorithms`
command. However, the title of the page is not in all caps ('List Of Algorithms'), while it's supposed to be in all caps, like the title of 'LIST OF FIGURES'.

Does anyone know how I can work around this? I tried to find a related option in `algorithm2e` package, but apparently there is no such an option.

Here is the document class, and the packages that I've used:

```
\documentclass[dissertation,CC-BY-SA]{uathesis}
\usepackage[ruled,boxed,noend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}         
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}         
\usepackage[bookmarks,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to patch the `\listofalgocfs` command to use `\MakeUppercase` for the macro containing the name:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\listofalgocfs}{\algocf@seclistalgo*{\listalgorithmcfname}}{\algocf@seclistalgo*{\MakeUppercase\listalgorithmcfname}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

[image]

The patching can also be done with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\listofalgocfs}{\algocf@seclistalgo*{\listalgorithmcfname}}{\algocf@seclistalgo*{\MakeUppercase\listalgorithmcfname}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, adding this worked:

`\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}`

(I'm using algorithm rather than algorithm2e)

Comment: But does that apply to algorithm2e, which is what the question is about?

Comment: No, but I thought others looking at this question would find this answer helpful. Maybe I should have commented instead

Answer (score 0):

For the algorithm2e package, a much simpler solution (than the accepted answer) has been provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346076/algorithm2e-rename-listofalgorithms-title). To sum up, just add the following line to the preamble -

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}
```