# Algorithm2e rename \listofalgorithms title

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

Can you help me to rename the title of `\listofalgorithms` (which is 'List of Algorithms') to another text? I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update `\listalgorithmcfname`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of Algorithmus}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the provided command `\SetAlgorithmName`, which takes 3 arguments: the new name of algorithms, the name to be used with `\autoref`, and the name to be used in the list of algorithms.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetAlgorithmName{Algorithmus}{Al.}{List of Algorithmi}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```