# Algorithm rename \listofalgorithms title

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, algorithmicx

How to rename the title of `\listofalgorithms`? If using the `algorithm` package (not `algorithm2e`)?

If you are using the `algorithm2e` package see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346095/169344).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In your question, you refer to `algorithm` as opposed to `algorithm2e`, but your tags suggest otherwise, so what do you want? Furthermore, it would be nice if you could provide a MWE (even if this question is self-answered, it should be a good post).

Answer (score 3):

Update `\listalgorithmname` before `\begin{document}`!

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of Algorithms}
```